# How to use lambda with pandas correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have the colomn in DataFrame where data are:

```
1      2017-07-14T04:00:00.3760000Z
2      2013-10-22T23:09:46.8630000Z
3      2015-01-14T16:07:05.0000000Z
4      2011-09-13T13:53:36.0000000Z
                   ...
332    2018-03-25T07:00:01.0000000Z
333    2019-04-08T15:21:02.0000000Z
334    2017-09-17T11:10:12.5100000Z
335    2017-12-22T07:31:16.0000000Z
336    2020-05-05T13:01:20.8670000Z
```

I need to delete the 'Z' and 'T' letters and transform them into a format like:

```
2018-05-23 17:26:19 and so on...
```

I used lambda in my code like:

```
import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('All_Markets.csv')
    print(df.dtypes)
    df['data_trade_start'] = [lambda x: x[:19].replace('T', ' ') for x in df['data_trade_start']]
    print(df['data_trade_start'])
```

And i got next strange format:

```
1      <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...

2      <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
3      <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
4      <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
                             ...
332    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
333    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
334    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
335    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
336    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x00000126690...
```

How can I change it into I wrote upper?

Comment: Does only `df = pd.read_csv('All_Markets.csv', parse_dates=False)` gets your desired output (`print(df)`)?

Comment: you are actually creating a column of lambda functions.  You want to use .apply() and put your lambda syntax inside of that

Comment: @ekrall Could you write to me here how i shoud write this code? I tried to use .apply, but it wasnt succesfull try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
df['data_trade_start'] = [x[:19].replace('T', ' ') for x in df['data_trade_start']]
# or
df['col'] = df['col'].replace(['T', 'Z'], [' ', ''], regex=True)
```

or convert it to datetime with `pd.to_datetime`

```py
df['data_trade_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data_trade_start'])
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me, but i add str(x).

Answer (score 0):

> df['data_trade_start'] = [lambda x: x[:19].replace('T', ' ') for x in df['data_trade_start']]

The problem is that you are creating a column whose values are lambda functions.

Try the following to convert a datetime column to a string in a given format

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('All_Markets.csv', parse_dates=['data_trade_start'])

df['data_trade_start'] = df['data_trade_start'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(df)
```

Comment: Man, i got the error with your code: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?

Comment: Did you include the `parse_dates` part in `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: TypeError: Only booleans, lists, and dictionaries are accepted for the 'parse_dates' parameter .                                                                                                                                       Maybe it can help you, colomn type in my DataFrame is:                 
data_trade_start         object

Comment: @Trepetaky I have updated my answer, it should work now. Consider doing this way, it's simpler and more readable.